# LRU sorted by score in C++, is there such container?

Tags: c++, sorting, caching, lru

I need to implement a very efficient cache LRU with the following properties: entries are indices in a vector of cache entries, each cache hit updates an empirical score, computed from some values that can be kept in the container value, like number of hits, size of matched object etc.

I need to be able to quickly pick a victim for cache eviction from the bottom of such LRU, and be able to quickly iterate over some number of the best-performing entries from the top, so such container needs to be sorted.

So far, I was only be able to come up with a vector of structures that hold values for score calculation that are updated, and bi-directional links, which I use to put the updated element in place after score recalculation by linear search from its current position and score comparison. This search may obviously happen upwards (when the score is updated, always getting bigger) and downwards (when an element is evicted, and its score resets to 0). Linear search may not be so bad, because this is running for a long time, and scores of elements that survive grow large, and each increment is small, so the element does not have to move very far to get to its place, and in case of reset I can start search from bottom.

I am aware of STL sorted containers, folly's cache LRU implementation, and Boost.Bimap (this last one seems to be an overkill for what I need).

Can I do better than a linear search here? Does anyone know of an implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: implemented a solution that involves a vector of iterators into a set that has index into the vector (for uniqueness) + necessary data to compute the score, with comparator sorting by the score.

Seems to work well, maybe there is a more elegant solution out there?